# Liquibase resets checksum and tries to rerun changesets when migrating to Spring Boot 2

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase

I'm migrating a Spring application which uses Liquibase 3.4.1 to Spring Boot 2.0.3. I'm still using Liquibase 3.4.1, altough I've also tried 3.6.1.

I added the liquibase configuration part in application.yml, but when I start the application the *MD5SUM* column in *DATABASECHANGELOG* is set to null for existing changesets and the application tries to rerun the changesets and it fails.

I added a new changeset for testing and for it it sets the *MD5SUM* value, but the column *LIQUIBASE* has the value *UNKNOWN* instead of *3.4.1*.

I'm not seeing anything relevant in the logs. I've also tried to run the application in debug mode.

Can someone help me out with some suggestions of what I could try? The application worked ok with Liquibase 3.4.1 without Spring Boot.

Below is my relevant application.yml config:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: ${RDS_URL}
    username: ${RDS_USERNAME}
    password: ${RDS_PASSWORD}
  jpa:
    show-sql: ${HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL}
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
    properties:
      generate_statistics: true
      globally_quoted_identifiers: true
      format_sql: ${HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL}
  liquibase:
    enabled: true
    change-log: classpath:/liquibase/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml
    user: ${RDS_USERNAME}
    password: ${RDS_PASSWORD}
    url: ${RDS_URL}
```

Comment: When you don't run it with Spring Boot it's not clearing the check sums? Do you see a message like "Clearing database change log checksums" in the log?

Comment: Without Spring Boot it's not clearing them.

Comment: Strange. Liquibase does have a function for clearing check sums but I do not see any reference to it (in the code) other than calling liquibase with the command `clearCheckSums`. Which would mean that somehow Spring Boot calls `clearCheckSums`. Sorry, I have no clue...

Comment: Thanks, I managed to make it work, but I'm not entirely sure why. I added a comment with what I did.

Answer (score 0):

Spring 1.5.X use liquibase-core-3.5.3.jar on the other hand 2.0.X use liquibase-core-3.5.5.jar.

There is a different on the liquibase code. If you look into the LiquibaseProperties.java you will see  prefix = "spring.liquibase" on   liquibase-core-3.5.5.jar and prefix = "liquibase" on liquibase-core-3.5.3.jar.

Now come to your point. Please look into yur liquibase version and use prefix accordingly. If you use older version remove spring from liquibase.

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: ${RDS_URL}
    username: ${RDS_USERNAME}
    password: ${RDS_PASSWORD}
  jpa:
   show-sql: ${HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL}
   hibernate:
     ddl-auto: none
  properties:
     generate_statistics: true
     globally_quoted_identifiers: true
     format_sql: ${HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL}

liquibase:
    enabled: true
    change-log: classpath:/liquibase/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml
    user: ${RDS_USERNAME}
    password: ${RDS_PASSWORD}
    url: ${RDS_URL}
```

Comment: If I use this config, besides the IDE telling me they are deprecated, the change-log file is not found. It's using the default one db.changelog-master.yaml. I've tried setting different strings for the change-log property but they aren't taken into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what I did, but now it's working ok. I changed the change-log value to *change-log: classpath:liquibase/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml* so without */* after classpath and I'm using liquibase version 3.6.1 with spring boot liquibase configurations having *spring* in front.

I have in the master file imports to other files. While I was debuging I saw that instead of matching the imported file to the ran changeset in the db it was matching the master file and so it tried to rerun the changeset, but now everything is ok. Weird.

Comment: Did you figure out why ? I have the same issue for a long time and I did not manage to find the time resolving it, sometimes it clear the checksums, sometimes it didn't

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<preConditions>` on your scripts to make sur your script should be executed otherwise you can record your changeset as `MARK_RAN`.

Here is an exemple of precondition :

```
<changeSet ...................>

    <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN" onError="CONTINUE">
        <not>
            <tableExists tableName="table_name_exemple"/>
        </not>
    </preConditions>

    <createTable tableName="table_name_exemple">

    </createTable>
</changeSet>
```